# Unable to install modman, .profile is missing

Tags: bash, .profile, modman

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/blob/master/README.md

I am trying to install modman.

First I install via:

```
bash < <(curl -s -L https://raw.github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/master/modman-installer)
```

modman is created at User/Username/bin/modman

I got lost on the next part:

```
source ~/.profile
```

I don't have .profile in my directory, so i created one in my user root and I added

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Username/bin/modman
```

I am not sure if that is correct, when I `cd` to my project directory and 
do `modman init` it returns `modman: command not found`

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: I did source it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add directories to `PATH`, not individual binaries.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Username/bin
```

Note the line from the installer that would have updated `.profile` for you:

```
echo -e '\nPATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.profile
```

(Typically, you might add `$HOME/bin` to the beginning of the path so that you can override system binaries, but in your case, it doesn't matter since you don't have `modman` installed outside your home directory.)

Comment: thank you so much, I never done anything like it, and don't even know where to start after much googling.